# Is “rape incidents befell American campuses” alright?

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context, synonyms

*Befall* is usually used as a synonym for happen or occur but with a negative connotation.

In this sentence, is the use of *befell* semantically correct?

> As a matter of fact, the majority of rape incidents that **befell** American campuses are acquaintance rape.

Comment: That's an unidiomatic and somewhat misleading use of *befell*. The rapes *befell* their **victims**, not the campuses of universities. The crimes, however, may have *occurred* on university campuses.

Comment: Also, either *befell* or *are* is the wrong tense.

Answer (score 1):

See the comment from Dan Bron.

This is a good pattern:

> [Is Media, Culture to Blame for US Virginia Tech Shootings](http://www.christiantoday.com/article/is.media.culture.to.blame.for.us.virginia.tech.shootings/10438.htm) ...
>
> Apr 19, 2007 - As the international community joins America in
>   mourning the recent tragedy that **befell students at Virginia Tech
>   University**, people around the globe have tried to explain the
>   reasons and motivations that could have led to the